# OpenLayer Maps not zooming

Tags: dictionary, zooming, openlayers

Initially the map zoom is set to 8, and that's the only place in the code i can change the zoom, any other location doesn't work.

I have a function that draws a marker and a route on the map (works just fine) but i cant change the zoom on that part.

When i try to change the zoom using
map.zoomTo(n) it just zooms to maximum
and
map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat), zoom)
also doesnt work.

I am trying to zoom the map after i have redrawn poly layer and marker layer.

Does anyone have any idea what could be done here?

Comment: Sometimes this sort of problem is caused by not setting maxExtent on the map, but it is hard to tell without seeing some code. Could you reproduce your problem and put it in jsfiddle.

Comment: manage to fixed it...

there was some redraw on layers and i had to timeout the zoom after the redraw... so it works perfectly now

Comment: Well done, always nice to find the solution yourself.